# What to do when the PDF file is not produced?

Tags: texmaker, thesis

I am new to LaTeX. Too amateurish! I would like to write up my Thesis in LaTeX. My learning progress was fantastic and I am half way preparing my document. Yet, some thing happened in middle of the course. without any signal the Texmaker stopped producing the PDF document. I can see on the PDF viewer that I am in page 50. However, the PDF produced is from last week; just stuck at page 32. Whatever I do now, the PDF file cannot be compiled. What do I do? Please help.

Comment: Welcome to TeX. SE! Well, we didn't see/(participate at) this event :( so it is difficult to say anything without an example, which has this behavior ...

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)! If you don't know what a minimal working example (MWE) is, click [here](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: Just a few general pointers: 1. try renaming your file then building it, 2. check the log files for any errors and warnings. That's all the help I can offer...

Comment: A classic case where an MWE is the best approach. Basically, keep commenting out more text (from end of document to start) until the error disappears. When the error disappears, slowly(!) start uncommenting text until the error re-appears. The `.log` file will often reveal approximately where it thinks the error is because it notes when it has shipped out a pagee.g., (`[32]` refers to page 32) and reports errors and warnings.

Comment: As a first step, try clearing all your auxiliary files -- if your thesis is in "thesis.tex", move all other files called "thesis.*" into a junk folder.

Comment: Short Explanation: You introduced an error by accident in your document, which confuses the Compiler that much, it just stops working. Nothing to worry about, as soon as the error is fixed, everything will be alright again.

Comment: I usually *cry havoc and let slip the dogs of war*! `:)` Welcome to TeX.sx, make yourself at home!

Comment: Another suggestion: IDEs like TeXMaker often run pdflatex in nonstop mode by default. This means the compiler will plough on through errors as best it can (which made sense about 30 years ago when documents were sent to a mainframe to be compiled). Try to find the setting for this and turn it off, so that pdflatex stops at the first error.